# How can I stop D3 chart from Duplicating on First Render in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, d3.js

For some reason, my D3 chart duplicates only on the first render. It will stack a second chart underneath the first vertically.

But when I hit refresh, it never duplicates again. Is there a way to make the **.forEach** loop once or put some kind of break or condition to prevent the duplicate render the first time?

Or do I need to modify the **useEffect()**?

```
export default function BarChart() {

    useEffect(() => {

        db.collection('revenue').get().then(res => { 
            let data = [];
            res.docs.forEach(doc => {   
                data.push(doc.data()); 
            });
      console.log(data);

            const svg = d3.select('.canvas')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', '640')
                .attr('height', '400');


            const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100 };
            const graphWidth = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
            const graphHeight = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            const graph = svg.append('g')
                .attr('width', graphWidth)
                .attr('height', graphHeight)
                .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

            // create axes groups
            const xAxisGroup = graph.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${graphHeight})`)

            const yAxisGroup = graph.append('g');

            const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.amount)])
                .range([graphHeight, 0]);

            const x = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(data.map(item => item.date))
                .range([0, graphWidth])
                .paddingInner(0.2)
                .paddingOuter(0.2);

            // join the data to circs
            const rects = graph.selectAll('rect')
                .data(data);

            // add attrs to circs already in the DOM
            rects.attr('width', '50')
                .attr("height", d => graphHeight - y(d.amount))
                .attr('fill', 'Red')
                .attr('x', d => x(d.date))
                .attr('y', d => y(d.amount));

            // append the enter selection to the DOM
            rects.enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('width', '50')
                .attr("height", 0)
                .attr('fill', 'Red')
                .attr('id', d => (d.id))
                .attr('x', (d) => x(d.date))
                .attr('y', graphHeight)
                .transition().duration(500)
                 .attr('y', d => y(d.amount))
                 .attr("height", d => graphHeight - y(d.amount))

            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
                .ticks(4)
                .tickFormat(d => d + ' dollars');

            xAxisGroup.call(xAxis);
            yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

            // Bottom Chart Text
            xAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
                .attr('fill', 'Teal')
                //.attr('font-weight', 'bold')
                .attr('transform', 'rotate(-40)')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        });

    }, []); // Array for data

    return (
        <div>
            <h1">Title</h1>
        </div>
    );

}
```

Comment: Does this only happen in development mode? It might be a hot-reloading issue.

Comment: I tried to get rid of the default onRequest cloud function in the functions/index.js file. At first it appeared to resolve the issue, but didn't. I thought maybe having two request response calls caused the app to call the firestore db twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to add an SVG to the component so

```
    return (
        <div>
            <h1">Title</h1>
            <svg className="svg-canvas" width="640px" height="400px" />
        </div>
    );
```

and change

```
const svg = d3.select('.canvas')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', '640')
  .attr('height', '400');

//to

const svg = d3.select('.svg-canvas')
svg.selectAll("*").remove()
```

This will make sure the SVG is always empty before a re-render. Though if your data update it will re-render everything.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH JC! This resolved the duplicate rendering. It worked perfectly! I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
export function component_name {data, ...props} {
    const yourRef = useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
        /*All your code here*/
        yourRef.current.append(X) /*"X" is your first SVG element that contains the others*/
        return() => X.remove()

    }, [data])}
```

Wherever you call your component:

```
<component_name data={data} />
```

Any time your data changes, your component will be erased.

Comment: Perfect, and in my opinion, the safest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I simple do this:

```
  // UseEffect
     React.useEffect(()=> {
          // Hide first svg
     let svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
        // If data present create chart
        if(data){
        // Create chart
       D3Chart(chartDiv.current, data);

// Hide first empty svg
       svg[0].style.display='none';
         }
     },[data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here I am, he

Also check if you have [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) enabled in your app, as it renders twice the wrapped tree component.